# Missing crash reason at developer console

Tags: java, android, kotlin

at my app crashes I see the line numbers and filenames, just not the extended crash reason. I get only things like "java.lang.NullPointerException:", without anything after it. It should contain more accurate data like when I reproduce the crash while debugging, something like "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method ..."

The same is happening even without using proguard, while using either Java or Kotlin. Something changed at the developer console that they no longer show it, or am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide the log or image of the log.

Comment: I just checked my console under `ANR & crashes` and the logs still seem to be quite comprehensive there.

Comment: for example https://image.ibb.co/cZ5YvF/crashdump.png . It was the same even when I disabled proguard.

Comment: @tibbi Could be possible that there is no further description, I mean `IllegalArgument` is pretty clear, or not? you got some popular app there btw, haha

Comment: its happening at all crashes, not just IllegalArgument. If I reproduce the crash while debugging, there is an additional sentence. I cant find the user feedback about crash either since the developer console was updated :/

Comment: Is there a nested `caused by` root-exception int the `IllegalArgumentExcdeption`? If so, please post the whole exception.

Comment: Please add the full stacktrace. This can be quite important.

Comment: here is an example of the whole crashdump http://image.ibb.co/fpBg2v/crashdump.png . Its happening at every crash, not just at IllegalStateExceptions.

Comment: Can you check if this is something happening on all devices which report crashes? Because I have found that some of my crash logs can be similar to what you have reported. The problem is that for some reason the device manufacturers tend to make it hard to send complete stack traces.

Comment: yes it is happening on all devices, ranging from Android 4 to 7. Doesnt matter if its java or kotlin, or if proguard is enabled or not. Im pretty sure Google messed something up, just as I cannot find user feedback about crashes anymore either.

Comment: Crash-reporting services think that exception messages may contain privte/sensitive information, and thus they don't show them.

Comment: It used to work before, so google apparently messed it up. If I switch to the old way of displaying crashes, I see them. I dont want to add Fabric as that requires interner permission :/

Comment: You can use Firebase crash reporting for more detailed report.
Link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/

Comment: I was considering firebase and fabric, but both need internet permission which I dont want to add just because of this.

Comment: You should post ether some info from your logcat, or discripe in what condition it happens.

E.g. I remember when I started with android, that I was surprised, that some variables are nulled, when App goes into background.

But nobody can give you a realy helpfull hint, if you do not give more information WHERE you get this Exception

Answer (score 0):

That is not an error at all. There is only nothing more to say than NullPointerException.

Your app ran into an Error caused by your fault which is found in line ...

So you go to that line and look for the Annotations like:

```
Returns:
    View: 
        The view that has the given id in the hierarchy or null
```

Than you can see that it may return null if the view with this ID is not existent, so if you are using it in such a situation like:

```
findViewByID(R.id.not_a_view).setOnClickListener(anyListener);
```

this throws a NullPointerException.

You don't need more Information.

Comment: it was just a simple example, I have issues with all crashes.

Comment: @tibbi My point was, that the information given is always enough to find the error.

Comment: I understood it, but thats just not true... Removing crash reason and user feedback really makes my life more difficult.